Filter large sheet with gspread
Exploring source code of gspread library discovered _finder method (findall() use it under the hood) of class Worksheet just store all data from table inside variable. It seems such behavior may occur problems when need find something inside really large table (about few thousands rows).
Does the gspread provide a way to lazily or partially load the contents of a large table for searching within it? Maybe I missed something in the documentation or source code? Thanks for any hint.
Try to find similar question and discover issues in gspread github with "lazy", "chunk", or "partial" table load.
